# Django AttributeError: 'ForeignObjectRel' object has no attribute 'through'

Tags: python, django

I have two django apps, app1 and app2. app1 has a ScenesConfig table, and then app2 has a Task. Their definitions are as follows:

```py
class ScenesConfig(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'scenes_config'
```

```py
from django.db import models
from app_1.models import ScenesConfig

class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    source_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    scenes = models.ForeignObject(ScenesConfig,
                                  from_fields=['source_type'],
                                  to_fields=['id'],
                                  null=True,
                                  related_name='task_scenes_config',
                                  on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name
```

At this point, I conducted my first migration and there were no errors. When I added a blank=True attribute to the scenes field of the task table the next time, an error occurred during the migration:

> Applying app_2.0003_auto_20230908_0256...Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/donghao/test/test_migations/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 356, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
> self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
> output = self.handle(*args, **options)
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 202, in handle
> post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
> state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
> state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
> state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
> operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 221, in database_forwards
> schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
> File "/Users/donghao/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/weicai/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 513, in alter_field
> old_field.remote_field.through and new_field.remote_field.through and
> AttributeError: 'ForeignObjectRel' object has no attribute 'through'

The new migration file is as follows：

```py
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_2', '0002_auto_20230908_0255'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='task',
            name='scenes',
            field=models.ForeignObject(blank=True, from_fields=['source_type'], null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING, related_name='ai_task_scenes_config', to='app_1.ScenesConfig', to_fields=['id']),
        ),
    ]
```

How to solve this problem? This blank attribute should not be at the database level, why should it be migrated? thanks

First, these two tables were created, migration was performed, and a blank=true field was added. Then, makemigrations was executed, and an error occurred during migration

Comment: It's `ForeignKey`, not `ForeignObject`. `ForeignObject` is an internal implementation detail that you shouldn't be bothered with. Also how can `source_type` (which is a string) be mapped to `id` (which is an integer)?

Comment: ForeignObject is currently only used as a query. I see that the description inside is' Abstraction of the ForeignKey ', but it seems that the usage method is incorrect. Thank you. That mapping is an example of an input error

Comment: I reported this problem in Django==2.1.7, and then I looked at the latest Django 4.2.5 source code and found that another error was reported, but they were similar problems. This was a BUG in Django. I have already mentioned it and fixed it in Django. ==4.2.6 will not appear anymore.  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/34820

Comment: Ah, ok. The code sample you posted in the bug report makes more sense (at least both `from` and `to` of the `ForeignObject` are integers). I'm glad that it has been resolved so quickly.